# String Concatenation with '"'

Tags: powershell

I have a string `$string = 'test test'` and I want the result `'"tets test"'`.

How can I concatenate `"` and `$string` without any spaces between?

My code:

```
$string = ' test test '
$string.Trim()
$result = '"' + $string +  '"'
echo $result
```

My result is:

```
" test test "
```

and I want the result `"test test"`.

Comment: use the string format operator `-f` - something like `$QuotedString = '"{0}"' -f $TrimmedString`

Comment: $result = '"' + $string.Trim() +  '"'

Answer (score 4):

The second line (`$string.Trim()`) isn't actually doing anything useful - it isn't trimming the string in-place they way you seem to expect.  Change your code to this instead:

```
$string = ' test test '
$result = '"' + $string.Trim() +  '"'
echo $result
```

Which should give the output:

`"test test"`

Comment: Alternatively (if you need it in other places too) assign the trimmed string back to the variable: `$string = $string.Trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use escape character in the double quotes (" ") like :

1)

```
$string =' test test '.Trim()
$result ="`"$string`""
echo $result
```

2)

```
$result ="`"$($string.Trim())`""
echo $result
```

Output will be the same..